# Function that returns Slice of Custom Interface

Tags: go, interface, slice

At first, I want to introduce you because I feel like I am missing some core Golang concept.

In my application, many models will have a method called GetByUserId. I created interface(UserCreatedEntity) that requires this method so then I will be able to create Controller's GetUserRecords method factory for each type of records with just:

```
router.Handle("/ideas/mine",
        middlewares.AuthUser(controllers.GetMineFactory(&models.Idea{}))).Methods("POST")

router.Handle("/votes/mine",
        middlewares.AuthUser(controllers.GetMineFactory(&models.Vote{}))).Methods("POST")

router.Handle("/someNewType/mine",
        middlewares.AuthUser(controllers.GetMineFactory(&models.SomeNewType{}))).Methods("POST")
```

This is how my interface looks like:

```
type UserCreatedEntity interface {
    GetByUserId(userId uint) []UserCreatedEntity
}
```

And implementation:

```
func (idea *Idea) GetByUserId(userId uint) []UserCreatedEntity {
    ideas := []Idea{}
    GetDB().
        Table("ideas").
        /** Query removed to make code less confusing **/
        Scan(ideas)

    return ideas
}
```

Obviously, it does not work (version with slice of pointers neither do). The thing is - This code would work if I return only one record - like that (obviously with changing signature in interface also):

```
func (idea *Idea) GetByUserId(userId uint) UserCreatedEntity {
    idea := &Idea{}
    GetDB().
        Table("ideas").
        /** Query removed to make code less confusing **/
        First(idea)

    return idea
}
```

How to make it work as slice? As I said I suspect that I am missing some important knowledge. So deep explaination would be awesome.

**Solution:**

```
func (idea *Idea) GetByUserId(userId uint) []UserCreatedEntity {
    ideas := []*Idea{}
    GetDB().
        Table("ideas").
        Select("problems.name AS problem_name, ideas.id, ideas.problem_id, ideas.action_description, ideas.results_description, ideas.money_price, ideas.time_price, ideas.is_published").
        Joins("INNER JOIN problems ON ideas.problem_id = problems.id").
        Where("ideas.user_id = ?", userId).
        Scan(&ideas)

    uces := make([]UserCreatedEntity, len(ideas))
    for i, idea := range ideas {
        uces[i] = idea
    }
    return uces
}
```

Comment: Copy over the elements of `idea` to a `[]UserCreatedEntity`: Each `*Idea` can be assigned to a UserCreatedEntity.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: Do not call them "arrays"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are dynamic. Composite types that involve interfaces are not.

`UserCreatedEntity` is an interface, and `Idea` satisfies the interface, so you can return an `Idea` from a function whose signature has a return type of `UserCreatedEntity`.

`[]UserCreatedEntity` is a slice of `UserCreatedEntity`, not an interface. The only type that can be returned is `[]UserCreatedEntity`. `[]Idea` is a different type (slice of `Idea`). You can fill a `[]UserCreatedEntity` with `Idea` *elements*, because each element is of type `UserCreatedEntity`, which again is an interface and `Idea` is allowed there.

Similarly, `func() UserCreatedEntity` is a type "function which returns `UserCreatedEntity`". You cannot subsitute a `func() Idea` because that is a different type. But you can return an `Idea` from a `func() UserCreatedEntity` because an `Idea` is a `UserCreatedEntity`.

If you weren't using `Scan` here, which presumably uses reflection, the fix would be to declare your local slice as `[]UserCreatedEntity` instead of `[]Idea`. Since you are using `Scan`, you instead must scan into a `[]Idea`, then iterate over it to copy all the elements to a `[]UserCreatedEntity` and return that.

Answer (score 4):

In programming language theory this is called *variance*, and [it is not supported in Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface). For much more details see [this proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21651).

Specifically, return types are not covariant. A slice of `T` does not implement a slice of `I` even if `T` implements `I`.

The FAQ entry linked above proposes this workaround:

> It is necessary to copy the elements individually to the destination
>   slice. This example converts a slice of int to a slice of interface{}:

```
t := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
for i, v := range t {
    s[i] = v
}
```

Though in your case the right solution may be different.